# Strings and getline character

Tags: c++

1. when i run the code, the output is my first and 
   last name and that's it.
2. I've used cin.clear, cin.sync and cin.ignore. 
   None of these seemed to work. However, when i used
   cin.fail, why did this work?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str_mystr;

    cout << "What is your name? ";
    getline (cin, str_mystr, '#');
    cout << "Hello " << str_mystr << '\n';
    // cin.ignore();
    cout << "What is your favorite city? ";
    getline (cin, str_mystr);
    cout << "I like " << str_mystr << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please add the input, expected output and what you are getting

Comment: Assuming you typed `first_name last_name#<enter>` the newline character is left in the input stream. Therefore your second getline just gets the new line. You could just do `getline(cin, str_mystr);`

Comment: Hello jignatius, I understand i could just do getline(cin, str_mystr). I just wanted to know could I use any of the input validations with the termination character. Sorry that I didn't make that clear in my previous code.

Answer (score 1):

just do what you did for name

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str_mystr;

    cout << "What is your name? ";
    getline (cin, str_mystr, '#');
    cout << "Hello " << str_mystr << '\n';
    // cin.ignore();
    cout << "What is your favorite city? ";
    getline (cin, str_mystr,'#');
    //                      ^^^^ 

    cout << "I like " << str_mystr << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

adding '#' will do the work just fine

Comment: @Oblivion it is not repeated, it is edited at line 14

Comment: Then highlight it in the code please. It is hard to find it. Or I can do it for you?

Comment: nice to mention @Oblivion, it seems like I do not know how to highlight it, I would be grateful if you do it please.

Comment: That is my taste BTW you don't have to follow. For such a question I would use only two lines as my answer body `cout << "What is your favorite city? ";
    getline (cin, str_mystr,'#');` Then give a live link to the full working code e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/g6M25r.

Comment: and please feel free to change my edit as you like.